# Como faço para ler duas colunas de um arquivo .dat em Python?

Tags: python

Tenho um arquivo .dat com os seguintes números:

```
34875    70.9300    -8.6700

54872    80.0500    16.2500

65456    77.0000    -5.5000

78787    78.2500    22.8300

20890    -8.9200    11.9300

87859    78.2500    15.4700

89556    80.6700    25.0000
```

Queria saber como que eu faria para ler apenas a segunda e a terceira coluna usando Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não especificaste o formato final que deveria ter, mas vou supor que é uma lista com várias sub listas, em que cada uma tem os dados da segunda e terceira coluna.

Podes fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
data = []
with open('tests.dat') as f: # abrir ficheiro em modo leitura ('r'), default, equivalente a ...open('tests.dat', 'r')...
    for line in f:
        if(line.strip() != ''): # exitem linhas vazias, vamos ignora-las
            cols = [i.strip() for i in line.split(' ')[1:]] # vamos quebrar cada linha por espacos e ignorar o primeiro valor de cada linha
            data.append(cols) # adcionar as cols desejadas a nossa lista principal
print(data) # [['70.9300', '-8.6700'], ['80.0500', '16.2500'], ['77.0000', '-5.5000'], ['78.2500', '22.8300'], ['-8.9200', '11.9300'], ['78.2500', '15.4700'], ['80.6700', '25.0000']]
```

Maneira mais didática:

```
data = []
with open('tests.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        if(line.strip() != ''): # exitem linhas vazias, vamos ignora-las, nao fazer nada com elas
            line_spl = line.split(' ') # vamos quebrar cada linha por espacos
            cols = line_spl[1:] # aproveitar o segundo e terceiro elemento da linha quebrada por espacos
            data.append([cols[0], cols[1].strip()]) # retirar '\n' do terceiro elemento, segundo em cols
print(data) # [['70.9300', '-8.6700'], ['80.0500', '16.2500'], ['77.0000', '-5.5000'], ['78.2500', '22.8300'], ['-8.9200', '11.9300'], ['78.2500', '15.4700'], ['80.6700', '25.0000']]
```

Podes imprimir a cada ciclo, linha, as `cols` desejadas:

```
with open('tests.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        if(line.strip() != ''):
            line_spl = line.split(' ')
            cols = [i.strip() for i in line.split(' ')[1:]]
            print(cols[0], cols[1].strip())
```

Comment: Opa!! Obrigado pela resposta Miguel!                                                                         então, desse jeito o script iria ler sem utilizar biblioteca nenhuma, certo?            Porém eu utilizei o Pandas para ler, e ficou mais "enxugado" o código.

Comment: @b3g1nn3er enxugado? O que é isso? Pois, eu não sabia que era com pandas, normalmente especificarias isso na pergunta. De nada, boa sorte

Comment: Enxugado seria "menos linhas de código". Sim, mas sua resposta também ajudou.

Answer (score 0):

Solução curta:

```
with open('arq.txt') as arq:
    dados = [line.split('    ')[1:] for line in arq.readlines() if line.strip()]
print(dados)
```